# Why Guavas Ordering doesn't sort string values of integers correctly?

Tags: string, sorting, guava

I want to know why Guavas `Ordering` doesn't works correctly at follows code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    System.out.println(Ordering.natural().isOrdered(integers));

    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
    System.out.println(Ordering.natural().isOrdered(strings));

    List<String> strings2 = Arrays.asList("6417", "6418", "6419", "6420");
    System.out.println(Ordering.natural().isOrdered(strings2));
}
```

***Output:***

```
true
false
true
```

I expected to see `true` 3 times.

***Can somebody explain why it isn't sorted as expected?***

Comment: Strings are sorted on the basis of their lexicographical ordering, and not on the basis of their something 'Integral' values..!
Their is no point of getting 'true' 3 times. String "1001" is smaller than "302", because "1001" would come before in the dictionary than "302". Got it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ordering of Strings is based on a lexicographical ordering as defined in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)), not on a numerical ordering. For a pair of Strings, the first character of each of them is taken and compared. Only if these are equal, the second character is looked at and so on. Thus the string `"10"` is "smaller" than the string `"9"`, because the character `'1'` is smaller than `'9'`.

Note that this is a part of the Java API, and is not specific to Guava. You can also look at the output of `"10".compareTo("9")` to see this. `Ordering.natural()` of Guava basically just calls the `compareTo` method of the compared objects.

The reason for this is that strings are arbitrary character sequences and it is not possible to interpret all of them as numbers, thus a numerical comparison would often fail. Other programming languages handle this in the same way.